# Necesito tratar un enumerado como si se tratase de un array en un jsp con jstl

Tags: java, jsp, enum, jstl

Por ahora estoy cargando los elementos del enumerado de forma manual, pero me gustaría saber si se puede recorrer con alguno de los componentes que facilita JSTL (`c:forEach` por ejemplo), ya que en el enum tengo 3 opciones, pero imaginaros si hay 500 opciones...

Éste es el enum:

```
public class Alumno extends Usuario implements Serializable {

    public enum Genero {
        HOMBRE,
        MUJER,
        OTRO;
//UPDATEADO
//Ya que no se pueden llamar a métodos estáticos desde un jsp es necesario crear éste método para acceder a el desde el jsp y obtener un array
        public Genero[] getValues() {
            return Genero.values();
        }
        }
        @Column(name = "Genero", length = 6)
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Genero genero;
    }
```

Ahora lo tengo así(forma manual):

```
<select class="form-control" id="generoEnum" name="generoEnum" title="Género">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${usuario.genero=='HOMBRE'}">
                        <option selected="" value="hombre">Hombre</option>
                        <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
                        <option value="otro">Otro</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${usuario.genero=='MUJER'}">
                        <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
                        <option selected="" value="mujer">Mujer</option>
                        <option value="otro">Otro</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${usuario.genero=='OTRO'}">
                        <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
                        <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
                        <option selected="" value="otro">Otro</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
                        <option selected="" value="mujer">Mujer</option>
                        <option value="otro">Otro</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </select>
```

He intentado hacerlo con mis experimentos pero sin éxito...
Gracias de antemano.

EDITO: para cerrar un poco más lo que busco es acceder al enum Genero desde el jsp, algo así (Ver la solución del compañero @Klaimmore

```
<c:forEach items="${Alumno.Genero}" var="genero">
       <option value="${genero}">${genero.simpleName()}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

EDITO2:
"usuario" es un objeto Alumno que está en sesión.

UPDATE para poner la traza:
Cuando yo logeo en la aplicación se carga en sesión(sessionScope) un objeto Alumno bajo el nombre "usuario", seguidamente yo hago click en un enlace en el menú lateral para cargar mediante AJAX una página en un div a la derecha:

```
//** cargamos un jsp genericamente en el panel de la derecha **//
    $(".opcion").click(function () {
        $.get("jsp/opciones_paneles/" + $(this).attr("id"), function (data, status) {
            $("#right-panel").empty();
            $("#right-panel").append(data);

            //lamamos al javascript de nuevo
             calljavascript();
        }); 
    });
```

Entonces es cargado un jsp que contiene el siguiente JSTL(actualizado con la posible solución del compañero @Klaimmore ):

```
<select class="form-control" id="generoEnum" name="generoEnum" title="Género">
                <c:forEach items="${Alumno.Genero.getValues()}" var="sexo">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${usuario.genero eq sexo}">
                            <option value="${sexo}" selected>${sexo.name()}</option>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <option value="${sexo}">${sexo.name()}1</option>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

La vista final sería ésta:
[image: VISTA]

Como podéis ver los demás campos se rellenan éllos solos con JSTL

#### SOLUCIÓN

Gracias a @Klaimmore por la solución!

El ejercicio trata de mostrar con un  un enum de Java en un JSP, en mi caso se visualizará en un `select`

1. Añadimos un método `getValues()` en el enum deseado

   ```
   public class Alumno extends Usuario implements Serializable, Comparable<Alumno> {

   public enum Genero {
       HOMBRE,
       MUJER,
       OTRO;

       public Genero[] getValues() {
           return Genero.values();
       }
   }
   @Column(name = "Genero", length = 6)
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Genero genero;
   ```

   }
2. Introducimos el  en el JSP deseado

[image: SELECT EN JSP]
(Pido disculpas por si molesta el código en la imagen, es el mismo trozo que abajo pero si quito la imagen el código no se me visualiza :/ )

```
<select class="form-control" id="generoEnum" name="generoEnum" title="Género">
            <c:forEach items="${usuario.genero.values}" var="sexo">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${usuario.genero eq sexo}">
                        <option value="${sexo}" selected>${sexo.name()}</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <option value="${sexo}">${sexo.name()}</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

Aquí un apunte:

- usuario = objeto java Alumno guardado en sessionScope

La chica en éste trozo es el:

[image: como llamar al método del enum en la clase Java]
(De nuevo pedir disculpas, no me visualiza el código :( )

Ésta cadena llama al método que hemos creado en el enum de Java

Espero que os sirva tanto como a mi, un saludo.

Comment: Las imágenes de código no son bien recibidas en SO. Pon mejor el código como texto para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: Editado, pensé que en las imágenes se vería mejor debido a los colores y tal, mis disculpas.

Comment: No entiendo porqué me ponen en espera la pregunta, ¿Demasiado amplia? ¿En serio? Pero si no puede ser más específica...

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con @Panbo no me parece que este mal formulada

Comment: Nada, seguimos en espera...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder esta pregunta un tanto vieja. No puedes mediante `EL` acceder a métodos estáticos, si puedes si te permites usar *scriptlets*:

```
<c:forEach items="<%= jsp.ejemplo.Alumno.Genero.values() %>" var="genero">
    <option value="${genero}">${genero.name()}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Como usar *scriptlets* es considerado una mala practica, tu otra opción es disponibilizar un método de instancia para obtener el listado de valores del `enum`, por ejemplo en el mismo `enum`:

```
public class Alumno extends Usuario implements Serializable {

    public enum Genero {
        HOMBRE,
        MUJER,
        OTRO;

        public Genero[] getValues() {
            return Genero.values();
        }
    }
    @Column(name = "Genero", length = 6)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Genero genero;
}
```

Y entonces usarlo a partir de una instancia válida como:

```
<c:forEach items="${alumno.genero.values}" var="genero">
    <option value="${genero}">${genero.name()}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Con eso, tu código para mostrar la `option selected` se simplificaría bastante:

```
<select class="form-control" id="generoEnum" name="generoEnum" title="Género">
    <c:forEach items="${alumno.genero.values}" var="genero">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${alumno.genero eq genero}">
                <option value="${genero}" selected>${genero.name()}</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${genero}">${genero.name()}</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Antes de nada agradecer tu comentario, más vale tarde que nunca :) Decirte que no se me permite usar scriptlets. He probado a meter el método dentro del enum, pero sin éxito, salta el error: "method values() is already defined in enum Genero", he intentado con @Override pero no lo permite. Fuera del enum no da error, pero aún así el select en el jsp se muestra vacío :( En el jsp también he intentado poner paréntesis al value de  ${alumno.lgenero.value} pero nada.

Comment: por alguna razon me equivoque al escribir la firma del metodo en el enum, deberia ser `getValues()`

Comment: Hola de nuevo, sigue sin funcionar, la parte del servlet la he modificado y ya no da error, en el jsp:
En la línea del forEach he probado de tu  manera y de ésta:
``` <c:forEach items="${Alumno.Genero.getValues()}" var="sexo">  ```
En la línea del when:
<c:when test="${usuario.genero eq sexo}">
<option value="${sexo}" selected>${sexo.name()}</option>
</c:when>. <br>
Perdona si se ve mal, no sé que etiquetas admite el mini-markdown :(

Comment: Al realizar el comentario hay un link de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) que te puede ayudar con el formato. Al respecto de tu problema, ¿sale algun error? ¿de que manera estas pasando los datos para ser visualizados en el jsp? recuerda que necesitas una instancia de alumno (y genero) para poder iterar sobre todos los generos

Comment: He updateado la pregunta inicial, espero que te sirva, un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Me llama la atención que uses `${Alumno.Genero.getValues()}` cuando la variable es `usuario`. Utiliza `${usuario.genero.values}`

Comment: Antes de nada muchísimas gracias!!!

He puesto la solución en el post principal, con unos ligeros cambios:
1. Cambiado "alumno" por "usuario" (nombre correcto de la variable en sessionScope) y genero por sexo(variable indice de <c:forEach>(creo que es más legible así)

Varias puntualizaciones finales:
1. Creía haberlo probado, pero probaría con la cadena <code>${alumno.genero.values}</code> pero claro, la variable se llama usuario
2. El punto 1 puede ser debido a que se me escapa la lógica de como poniendo values accede al método getValues()
PD: El mejor regalo de cumpleaños ^^.

Comment: Respecto al punto 2 en el que hago referencia a que no pillo la lógica, será lo mismo que cuando hago referencia a un atributo por ejemplo usuario.nombre éste accede a getNombre().

Comment: @Panbo efectivamente, con [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahx) tu referencias a las propiedades mediante sus nombres simples usando sus accesadores, siguiendo las convenciones de nombres de componentes JavaBean